# Using libreoffice base as GUI for MySQL database (os- ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: server, java, libreoffice, mysql

I have been trying to deploy one of my projects that uses jsp for the front end, tomcat7 for the server and a mysql database. I tried integrating the mysql database with the libreoffice database because I had to copy a lot of data from existing excel sheets and then paste it into the database. I downloaded the connector from the MySQL site and put it in the library of tomcat7. I modified the class path to include this .jar file into it. Now I run my server and start my project and I encounter a null pointer exception while obtaining the connection.I am posting my code here

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Database_name","root",password");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a connexion, this code:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver (new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
m_Connexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Database_name","root",password);
```

should work. Maybe yours too if you quote correctly the `password` (you should have "password" or password, not password").

If it still don't work you should check the url, username and password.